# Javascript - Skeleton Content Placeholder

Tags: javascript

This function displays a style for `:empty` HTML elements (designed to look like a placeholder) until `page load`, then injects some content into these elements thus removing the `:empty` style and revealing the content.

How do I simply show the placeholders until existing HTML content is loaded without using `:empty` and injecting it through JS? I want to already have data for the `h1`, `p` and `img` and have a placeholder show for these elements during `page load`.

```js
var
  image = document.querySelector('.sk-image'),
  heading = document.querySelector('.sk-heading'),
  paragraph = document.querySelector('.sk-paragraph');

var content = false;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (content === false) {
      content = true;
      image.src = 'http://unsplash.it/400/400?image=564';
      heading.innerHTML = 'Some heading';
      paragraph.innerHTML = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa rerum porro aut laboriosam animi.';
    } else {
      content = false;
      image.src = '';
      heading.innerHTML = '';
      paragraph.innerHTML = '';
    }
  }, 2000);
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.card__image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 60%;
  background: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card__image:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  animation: loading 1.5s infinite;
}

.card__image img {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.card__content {
  padding: 20px;
}

.card__heading {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.card__heading:empty {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background: #d8d8d8;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.card__paragraph {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.35;
}

.card__paragraph:empty {
  width: 90%;
  height: 20px;
  background: #d8d8d8;
}

.button {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #2aa1c0;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #0e647d;
}

@-moz-keyframes loading {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes loading {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes loading {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes loading {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__image">
    <img class="sk-image" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="card__content">
    <h1 class="card__heading sk-heading"></h1>
    <p class="card__paragraph sk-paragraph"></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__image">
    <img class="sk-image" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="card__content">
    <h1 class="card__heading sk-heading"></h1>
    <p class="card__paragraph sk-paragraph"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might use a class, like `.card__heading-loading`, but it might help if you explain why you don't want to use `:empty`

Comment: Because there will already be content inside of the div